# Repository method not found

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, symfony4

I have created a method to query to database for all joining table in repository. I also have read the documentation from [How to create custom repository](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine/repository.html). The method is working properly, but in PhpStorm there is a yellow warning

> Method 'findAllDetail' not found.

How do I fix this warning?

Below is my entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\InvoiceRepository")
 */
class Invoice
{
```

and here is the `InvoiceRepository`:

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Invoice;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

/**
 * @method Invoice|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Invoice|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Invoice[]    findAll()
 * @method Invoice[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
  */
 class InvoiceRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
 {
     public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
     {
         parent::__construct($registry, Invoice::class);
     }

     /**
      * @param $value
      * @return Invoice[] Returns an array of Invoice objects
      */
     public function findAllDetail($value)
     {
         $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
             /* .... */
         ;
         return $qb->execute();
     }
```

and here is the controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/invoice/review/{idInvoice}", name="submitToReview", requirements={"idInvoice"="\d+"})
 * @param $idInvoice
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function submitToReview($idInvoice, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $invoice = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Invoice::class)->findAllDetail($idInvoice);
    /* @var $item \App\Entity\Invoice */
```

Comment: Are you using phpstorm Symfony plugin? You are using your repository as a service, so getting it directly should work `$this->get(Invoice:class)->findAllDetail($idInvoice);`

Comment: It did remove the yellow warning, but it didn't work. i get "You have requested a non-existent service "App\Entity\Invoice" error in my app.

Comment: You don't pass entity, but repositor as parameter to your controller - `public function submitToReview($idInvoice, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, InvoiceRepository $repository)`

Comment: Thanks M.Kebza, your answer fix my issue!

Answer (score 2):

For those people who get the same warning, below is how i fix it (based on M. Kebza Comment)
put your repository in controller and pass repository as parameter in the controller

in controller

```
... 
use App\Repository\InvoiceRepository; 

 /**
  * @Route("/invoice/review/{idInvoice}", name="submitToReview", requirements={"idInvoice"="\d+"})
  * @param $idInvoice
  * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
  */
 public function submitToReview($idInvoice, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, InvoiceRepository $repository )
 {
     $invoice = $repository->findAllDetail($idInvoice);
     /* @var $item \App\Entity\Invoice */
```

Comment: It seems wrong that phpStorm is forcing changes to working code; this is more clutter than clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Basically when you do

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository()
```

It returns a Doctrine **EntityRepository**. So that's normal if phpstorm is complaining about your findAllDetails method because EntityRepository does not know it.

From the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories):

> By default the EntityManager returns a default implementation of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository when you call EntityManager#getRepository($entityClass).

So even if you override this behavior as suggested in the doc, I suppose that phpstorm keeps reference to the default.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying,

Answer (score 1):

Repository class make public in services.yaml file and call in controller

```
$invoiceRepository = $this->get(InvoiceRepository::class);
```

or

```
/** @var InvoiceRepository $invoiceRepository **/
$invoiceRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Invoice::class);

$invoice = $invoiceRepository->findAllDetail($idInvoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would construct the controller with the repository (and the mailer) rather than put it into the action - the autowiring will sort the injection, there's no uri parameter confusion, and it's good to be explicit - your future self will thank you:

```
# Controller.php

/**
 * @var InvoiceRepository
 */
private $invoiceRepo;

/**
 * @var \Swift_Mailer
 */
private $mailer;

/**
 * @param InvoiceRepository $invoiceRepo
 * @param \Swift_Mailer $mailer
 */
public function __construct(InvoiceRepository $invoiceRepo, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $this->invoiceRepo = $invoiceRepo;
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}

/**
 * @Route("/invoice/review/{idInvoice}", name="submitToReview", requirements={"idInvoice"="\d+"})
 * @param $idInvoice
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function submitToReview($idInvoice)
{
    $invoice = $this->invoiceRepo->findAllDetail($idInvoice);
    ...
}
```